# Eisenstein series of this lattice

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, vector-spaces, integer-lattices

Given a lattice $L$ and an integer $n\ge4$ we can calculate a number — the Eisenstein series of the lattice:

$$G_{n}(L) = \sum _{\omega \in L, \omega \neq 0} \frac{1}{\omega ^{n}}.$$

> How do we calculate the Eisenstein series of the lattice below?

$X_2 = w_1^{\mathbb Z} \odot w_2^{\mathbb Z},$ where $w_1=(a,1)$ and $w_2=(1,b)$ for some $a,b>0; a,b\neq 1,$ and $(x_1,y_1)\odot(x_2,y_2)=(x_1 x_2, y_1 y_2)$ and $w^{\mathbb Z} = \{ w^n \mid n \in \mathbb{Z} \}.$

Can we use the $G_n(L)$ or do we need something different?

For example:

$$G_{4}(\mathbb{Z}) = \sum _{n \neq 0} \frac{1}{n^{4}} = 2 \zeta (4) = 2 \frac{\pi ^{4}}{90}$$

I'm having trouble convincing myself that

$$G_4(X_2) = \sum _{n \neq 0} \frac{1}{n^{4}} = 2 \zeta (4) = 2 \frac{\pi ^{4}}{90}$$

What seems to be apparent is that $X_2\simeq \Bbb Z.$ In other words $X_2$ is a transported lattice under the $\exp$ mapping. This transport of structure allows one to pass information from the lattice $\Bbb Z$ to the lattice $X_2$.

A natural question is how to pass the Eisenstein series from $\Bbb Z$ to $X_2,$ which is my question.

Comment: Aren't Eisenstein series for discrete additive subgroups of $\Bbb C$? Also $\{(a^m,b^n)\mid m,n\in\Bbb Z\}$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z^2$ via $(a^m,b^n)\leftrightarrow (m,n)$.

Comment: @runway44 yes so what would be the analog for Eisenstein series for the discrete multiplicative subgroup of $\Bbb C?$ would it be an infinite product instead of sum?

Comment: What you've written is a discrete multiplicative subgroup of $(\Bbb R^\times)^2$, not $\Bbb C^\times$. The Eiseinstein series is related to both the addition and multiplication operations of $\Bbb C$'s field structure, since a lattice is an additive subgroup but its elements' powers are being summed. Your group is related to $\Bbb C$'s additive structure (and only abstractly at that), but doesn't appear at all related to its multiplicative structure. So I don't see why there would be an analog.

Comment: there has to be an analogue. because the underlying fields are $\Bbb C$ and something isomorphic to $\Bbb C$. I presume the latter may have complicated operations. Potentially there is no simple representation of the analog and it can only be computed very abstractly

Comment: I would say the "underlying field" of $(\Bbb R^\times)^2$ is $\Bbb R$, not $\Bbb C$.

Comment: what im saying is that $\Bbb R^2_{\gt 0} $ is a subspace of something isomorphic to $\Bbb C,$ called $X.$ So the operations on $X$'s field structure will be related to an Eisenstein analog

Comment: $X$ is a group, it does not have a field structure, and its group operation is not related to $\Bbb C$'s multiplication (except in that $\Bbb C$ happens to have $\Bbb R$ inside it). To me its group operation doesn't even appear to be naturally related to $\Bbb C$'s *additive* structure (only "abstractly" related, in the same vein as the phrase "abstract isomorphism").

Comment: The $\exp$ mapping I mentioned in the post let's one transport the field structure from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R_{\gt 0}.$ you can get field operations. you can complexify the latter. But as I was saying, the $\exp$ mapping makes writing down compatible field operations for the complexification difficult. So maybe there's little use in the exercise

Comment: But you're not using a complexification so that's just irrelevant.

Comment: I guess I was assuming that the lattice $X_2$ was sitting in this complexification of $\Bbb R_{\gt 0}$ as a subset. Sitting in $\Bbb R^2_{\gt 0}$ as a discrete subset as well

Comment: If you do that, you have $X_2$ as a multiplicative copy of $(\Bbb Z^2,+)$ sitting inside a multiplicative copy of $(\Bbb C^2,+)$ as a complex vector space, which is still not analogous.

Comment: Do you mean $(\Bbb C, +)$ there?

Comment: No. Your $X_2$ is inside $(\Bbb R^\times)^2$, which is a multiplicative version of $(\Bbb R^2,+)$ (or technically its identity component is), whose complexification would be $(\Bbb C^2,+)$, inside which $(\Bbb Z^2,+)$ (what $X_2$ corresponds to) would have span with $\dim_{\Bbb C}=2$ (as opposed to a lattice in $(\Bbb C,+)$ whose span has $\dim_{\Bbb C}=1$).

Comment: So $X_2$ as a multiplicative copy of $(\Bbb Z^2,+)$ sitting inside a mult. copy of $(\Bbb C^2,+)$ as a complex vector space.... are you saying there's no way to characterize the lattices using Eisenstein series like is possible with $(\Bbb C,+)$?

Comment: Right. For one, $\Bbb Z^2$ is not a lattice in $\Bbb C^2$ like $\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Zi$ (e.g.) is in $\Bbb C$. And two, $\Bbb C^2$ does not have a multiplicative operation. You could do "sums over discrete rank 2 free abelian subgroups" of the quaternions, but I'm doubtful that would lead to characterization results like it does for complex numbers. (The only holomorphic quaternionic functions are affine functions, and I think holomorphy is important to the theory.) Either way, writing everything multiplicatively is unnecessary, and your $X_2$ is not defined using any complexifications anyway.